# Who calls the metaclass

Tags: python, python-2.7, metaclass

This actually stems from a discussion here on SO.

**Short version**

```
def meta(name, bases, class_dict)
    return type(name, bases, class_dict)

class Klass(object):
    __metaclass__ = meta
```

`meta()` is called when `Klass` class declaration is executed.

Which part of the (python internal) code actually calls `meta()`?

**Long version**

When the class is declared, some code has to do the appropriate attribute checks and see if there is a `__metaclass__` declared on a type. If such exists, it has to perform a method call on that metaclass with the well known `(class_name, bases, class_dict)` attributes. It is not really clear to me which code is responsible for that call.

I have done some digging in CPython (see below), but I would really like to have something closer to a definite answer.

**Option 1: Called directly**

The metaclass call is hardwired into the class parsing. If so, is there any evidence for this?

**Option 2: It is called by `type.__new__()`**

Code in [`type_call()`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Objects/typeobject.c#L890) calls [`type_new()`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Objects/typeobject.c#L2276) which in turn calls [`_PyType_CalculateMetaclass()`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Objects/typeobject.c#L2241). This suggests that metaclass resolution is actually done during the call to `type()` when trying to find out which value to return from `type()`

This would be in in line with the notion that a "class" is a "*callable that returns an object*".

**Option 3: Something different**

All my guesses maybe completely wrong, of course.

> Some example cases that we came up with in chat:

**Example 1:**

```
class Meta(type):
    pass

class A:
    __metaclass__ = Meta

A.__class__ == Meta
```

This is what `Meta.__new__()` returns, so this seems legit. The metaclass puts itself as `A.__class__`

**Example 2:**

```
class Meta(type):
    def __new__(cls, class_name, bases, class_dict):
        return type(class_name, bases, class_dict)

class A(object):
    __metaclass__ = Meta

A.__class__ == type
```

Edit 2: correct initial version, properly derive `Meta` from `type`.

Seems okay enough, but I'm not really sure this does what I think it does. Also: What is the canonical method to make it behave like in Example 1?

Edit 3: Using `type.__new__(...)` seems to work as expected, which also seems in favor of Option 2.

Can anybody with more in-depth knowledge of internal python magic enlighten me?

Edit: A for a quite concise primer on metaclasses: http://blog.ionelmc.ro/2015/02/09/understanding-python-metaclasses/. Also has some really nice diagrams, references and also highlights the differences between python 2 and 3.

Edit 3: There is a good answer below for Python 3. Python 3 uses [`__build_class__`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1832997/what-does-pythons-builtin-build-class-do) to create a class object. The code path is --however-- different in Python 2.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/100003/what-is-a-metaclass-in-python

Comment: FWIW, the original discussion was about whether `SomeClass()` resolves to `SomeClass.__class__.__call__()` (which will eventually delegate to `type.__new__()`, or if iit resolves to `type.__call__()` (which would the delegate to `SomeClass.__class__.__call__`).

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers I think we have that resolved now and it is the former. Still some riddles open, though :)

Comment: @dhke looks like I've missed something... care to enlighten me ?

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22083327/does-the-default-type-call-do-more-than-call-new-and-init seems to suggest that you can do quite evil stuff by overridng `__class__.__call__` which is called directly. Both paths somewhere call `type.__new__()` so the question here is still unanswered.

Comment: @dhke now it is obviously ;)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can find the answer relatively easily. First, lets find the opcode for building a class.

```
>>> def f():
    class A(object):
        __metaclass__ = type

>>> import dis
>>> dis.dis(f)
  2           0 LOAD_CONST               1 ('A')
              3 LOAD_GLOBAL              0 (object)
              6 BUILD_TUPLE              1
              9 LOAD_CONST               2 (<code object A at 0000000001EBDA30, file "<pyshell#3>", line 2>)
             12 MAKE_FUNCTION            0
             15 CALL_FUNCTION            0
             18 BUILD_CLASS         
             19 STORE_FAST               0 (A)
             22 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
             25 RETURN_VALUE
```

So the opcode is `BUILD_CLASS`. Now let's search the source for that term (easily done on the [github mirror](https://github.com/python-git/python)).

You get a couple of results, but the most interesting of which is [`Python/ceval.c`](https://github.com/python-git/python/blob/715a6e5035bb21ac49382772076ec4c630d6e960/Python/ceval.c) which declares the function `static PyObject * build_class(PyObject *, PyObject *, PyObject *);` and has a case statement for `BUILD_CLASS`. Search through the file and you can find the function definition of `build_class` starting at line 4430. And on line 4456 we find the bit of code you are looking for:

```
result = PyObject_CallFunctionObjArgs(metaclass, name, bases, methods,
                      NULL);
```

So the answer is the metaclass is resolved and called by the function that is responsible for executing the `BUILD_CLASS` opcode.

Comment: Looks like a python 3 example - the OP asked about how it works in python 2.7.x

Comment: Code is from https://github.com/python-git/python which is for 2.7. Look at the `build_class` function more carefully can you can see it's definitely 2.7 it's actually looking for the name `__metaclass__`, which is ignored in 3.x.

Comment: Yep, this is the answer for Python 2. I was just about to update my answer to say roughly the same thing. I'll still update my answer a bit, but you get a +1 from me as well!

Comment: So it's indeed Option 1, as the parser explicitly generates code for the class generation which directly invokes `__metaclass__.__call__()`. Need to figure out what `_PyType_CalculateMetaclass()` actually does then.

Comment: Side note: You can directly link the github search: https://github.com/python-git/python/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=BUILD_CLASS

Comment: @dhke The more you know. Thanks. `_PyType_CalculateMetaclass` is mainly for detecting metaclass conflicts. That is, a class can only have one metaclass. If a class or its bases have metaclasses that are not strict subtypes then there could be weird issues. In addition if the current class declares it's metaclass as `MetaParent` and one of its bases uses `MetaChild`, then `MetaChild` will be used instead to keep the metaclass hierarchy consistent.

Comment: @Dunes: Thanks for all the effort you put into this. I think we've all had a very instructive day by now. Also: Thanks for reminding me that I can just pull out the byte code at will if needed.

Answer (score 2):

In Python 3, the metaclass is called in the code for the [`__build_class__`](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/8667c26e2bec/Python/bltinmodule.c#l52) builtin function (which is called to handle `class` statements). This function is new in Python 3, and the equivalent C function `build_class` in Python 2 is not publicly exposed at the Python level. You can however find the source in [`python/ceval.c`](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/a985b6455fde/Python/ceval.c#l4935)

Anyway, here's the relevant call to the metaclass object in the Python 3 `__build_class__` implementation:

```
cls = PyEval_CallObjectWithKeywords(meta, margs, mkw);
```

The variable `meta` is the metaclass (either `type` or another metaclass found from an argument or from the type of a base class). `margs` is a tuple with the positional arguments `(name, bases, dct)` and `mkw` is a dictionary with the keyword arguments to the metaclass (a Python 3 only thing).

The Python 2 code does something similar:

```
result = PyObject_CallFunctionObjArgs(metaclass, name, bases, methods,
                                      NULL);
```

Answer (score -4):

Meta classes are "instantiated" by interpreter when class definition is executed.